# How to opt out from dark mode on a MacOS app?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, darkmode, lightmode

I want to set my swift app to always be in Light mode (to opposite to auto dark/light). All articles I could find on internet are for iOS and don't seem to work - being `UIUserInterfaceStyle` to Light, `UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle` to .light..., or even looking for an option in the Interface Builder.
I am not using a viewController class but have my code directly in AppDelegate, hence no viewDidLoad.
What's the way to force light mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In applicationDidFinishLaunching, add the following line:

```
window.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .vibrantLight)
```

Comment: NSApp.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .vibrantLight) on AppDidFinishedLoading was also worked for me.

Comment: more info : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancecustomization/choosing_a_specific_appearance_for_your_macos_app#2993819